# How can I create a PDF file in classic ASP?

Tags: pdf, web-applications, asp-classic, pdf-generation

Is there any way to generate PDF files from classic ASP? I have a bunch of user-entered data that needs to be turned into a PDF that the user can download. How can I do this? OpenOffice allows exporting documents to PDF, so could this somehow be leveraged?

Answer (score 3):

I played around a bit with this (Persits ASPPDF): http://www.asppdf.com/

Comment: That is what we use, and it seems to do pretty much anything we need.

Comment: This looks promising, but less costly(aka. gratis) options are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe running an external application that could be using CrystalReports... and you just pass it as an xml?

That's how i would do it... (lazy mode)

Comment: Do you know of any other external applications that can take xml and do this? Can OpenOffice do this?

Comment: I don't know for sure... i think that infopath maybe can achieve this... but it's just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

See a full list of PDF components here: http://www.aspin.com/home/components/document/pdf Many of them are free.

It is also possible to use XSLT to output PDF but I am not sure if this is supported by the Microsoft XML Parser. I remember there were something stopping me when I tried to do this 3-4 years ago. Might be worth checking out know depending out the type of data you have as source.

However if these are static files or a one time job consider using a PDF converter on your computer and just upload the files to the server. There are heaps of tools for this, including Adobe Acrobat.