# converting HTML form to PDF in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a form in classic asp, I want to convert that form into pdf without using any third party.pls help me

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Classic ASP has no inbuilt support. Best you could do is make a print css and get the user to PDF that.

There are 3rd party tools that will do it see this question [How can I create a PDF file in classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440905/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-file-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a few steps.

1. Save to Word document using code below.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <%@ Language=VBScript %>
   <% 
   Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
   Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=PRINT_TEST.doc"
   %>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
   <title>PRINT TEST</title>
   </head> 
   <body>
   Hello! This is a Word File.
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

NOTE: Word doc does not take linked .css file. If you need to add HTML styles you will have to type them into this file between  tag.

2. Save Word .doc file on the webserver (TEMP DIR)
3. Use simple Python batch script to convert Doc to PDF on a fly (snippet of Python code below)

   ```
   inDocFile = SOURCE_DIR+DOC_FILE_NAME
   outPDFFile = OUTPUT_DIR+DOC_FILE_NAME[:-4]+".PDF"

   in_file = os.path.abspath(inDocFile)
   out_file = os.path.abspath(outPDFFile)

   word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
   doc = word.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath(inDocFile))
   doc.SaveAs(os.path.abspath(outPDFFile), FileFormat=17)
   doc.Close()
   word.Quit()
   ```
4. Open PDF file from temp location

This is a multistep process but works like a charm. Good luck!