# How do i export a PDF correctly on classic asp without external application?

Tags: html, pdf, vbscript, asp-classic, pdf-generation

i have this question about how to generate a PDF file from a webpage on asp, i can generate a Word document and Excel but i can't yet create a pdf document on asp, i have a workmate who told me he could generate a pdf file with just asp code, nothing external so i would like to ask to you how this could be done.

currently i tried the method that creates some Excel and Word files, i tried converting it to pdf but the file gets exported incorrectly therefore the file exports corrupted and it can't be visualized

this is code i'm trying currently

```
Response.ContentType="application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=download.pdf"
```

however this code works fine when generating a Word document

```
Response.ContentType="application/vnd.msword"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=download.doc"
```

what could be causing the file to get exported incorrectly? thanks in advance, any help Will always be grateful

Comment: *'however this code works fine when generating a Word document'* - no, it does not. Your original format merely is something Word by chance knows to handle, too, and your code cheats browser and operation system to start it in word.

Comment: You can't do that with pure classic ASP, you must use some external DLL for that. You can find few [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440905/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-file-in-classic-asp)

Comment: hi @mkl and thanks for your answer, for what i need for a Word document is enough, and by the way what do you mean with it is barely something Word knows how to handle? you mean it needs more work than that?

Comment: hi @ShadowWizard and thanks for your answer as i said my partner of job has done this but he claims he done it with pure asp code, so he is either lying or downloaded some external libraries?

Comment: so i recently tried generating a pdf document and it exported without issues, however when i tried to visualize the file it says download.asp instead of download.pdf why does this happen?

Comment: *"for what i need for a Word document is enough, and by the way what do you mean with it is barely something Word knows how to handle? you mean it needs more work than that?"* - MS Word can open files in a number of formats. I assume you returned plain text or HTML, both formats Word can handle. Nonetheless neither a plain text nor a HTML file would be considered Word documents. Thus, if your project is not merely a fun project and if the functionality "MS Word document export" was promised, the client you develop it for may eventually approach you and ask you to really implement than function

Comment: @black-soul as the other user (mkl) tried to explain, you can open pure text files with programs like Word or PDF, sometimes. This does not make the pure text file a Word document, or a PDF file. It's still just pure text.

Comment: Define "external", do you mean external to the server? external 3rd party service? external to what comes with classic ASP? If you are able to install library's or phantomJS you can do it "internal to the instance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that in classic asp, you can either buy a library from internet with that stock function (that obviously could cost you money) or you can load the print page that gives you the option of creating a PDF file